# Float to String Conversion - JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, floating-point, type-conversion, numbers

So I am currently working on that function

```
const countSixes = n => {
  if (n === 0) return 0;
  else if (n === 1) return 1;
  else n = (countSixes(n-1) + countSixes(n-2)) / 2;

  return n;
}
```

And so my question is how to convert the final floating-point value into a string?

Every time after calling the function and trying to convert the float number it returns NaN

---

## What I've Tried

1. "" + value
2. String(value)
3. value.toString()
4. value.toFixed(2)

---

Hope to get the answer

Thank you!

Comment: what value do you expect? please add an example.

Comment: I copied your function exactly as posted, ran it in the chrome console and added a toString() at the end of the call and got a string output, what value are you calling this function with?

Comment: Each of those should work , can you give a larger example and explain what you want and what happens instead?

Comment: Issue is you are using it in recursive manner so you probably were using inside the function call so you were subtracting strings? Hard to tell since you did not show how you were converting it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

The first option works for me

```html
<script>
const countSixes = n => {
  if (n === 0) return 0;
  else if (n === 1) return 1;
  else n = (countSixes(n-1) + countSixes(n-2)) / 2;

  return n;
}

alert(countSixes(12) + "")
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is really interesting. Its `return` `NaN` because when you return `n` as `String`, as the `function` is called recursively so it cannot perform arithmetic operations in next level.
It will never end for certain numbers like `55`

```
function countSixes(n,firstTime=true){
        if (n === 0) return 0;
        else if (n === 1) return 1;
        else n = (countSixes(n-1,false) + countSixes(n-2,false)) / 2;
        if(firstTime) return n.toFixed(10);    // return string
        else return parseFloat(n.toFixed(10));      // return float
    }
```

Comment: I would define `countSixes()` as entry and `countSixesHelper()` as recursive part.

Comment: I would also do that but i posted this in hurry

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the final value to a string with the wanted decimals.

```js
const countSixes = n => {
    if (n === 0) return 0;
    if (n === 1) return 1;
    return (countSixes(n - 1) + countSixes(n - 2)) / 2;
}

console.log(countSixes(30).toFixed(15));
```